# Send an intent to cast a youtube video on a MediaRoute in Android?

Tags: android, youtube, mediarouter

From my Android App I would like to  
start casting a youtube video  
on a ChromeCast.

I understand, that to start casting I will need to use the Media Router API.

Is that possible to cast youtube videos using Media Router API?
I have not found any possibility to do so within the [YouTubeIntents list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents)